# Haskell beginner - optimal way to solve this

Tags: haskell

I was assigned the task to create a function which is able to calculate the grade of your exam by adding the points you achieved to the extra points you collected through other means and then converting them into the grade system. I also had to add an error message if either the extra points or the exam points exceeded their maximum (20 and 100 respectively).

The function I created works, but it probably isn't close to being optimal.

```
calcGrade :: Double -> Double -> Double
calcGrade x y
| x > 20 = error "Can't add more than 20 extra points"  
| y > 100 = error "Can't achieve more than 100 points"
| x + y < 50 = 5.0 
| x + y >= 50 && x + y < 54 = 4.0
| x + y >= 54 && x + y < 58 = 3.7
| x + y >= 58 && x + y < 62 = 3.3
| x + y >= 62 && x + y < 66 = 3.0
| x + y >= 66 && x + y < 70 = 2.7
| x + y >= 70 && x + y < 74 = 2.3
| x + y >= 74 && x + y < 78 = 2.0
| x + y >= 78 && x + y < 82 = 1.7
| x + y >= 82 && x + y < 86 = 1.3
| x + y >= 86               = 1.0
```

Is there another way of doing this or is there anything I could do more efficiently? I'm pretty new to Haskell and programming in general so I'm thankful for any advice!

Comment: By the way, if you're interested in a review (and your code works), try [CodeReview.SE].

Answer (score 2):

If I wanted to implement *that exact same function* (as opposed to changing the specification so that I could make the code cleaner -- which is sometimes possible), I think I would use `Map`'s `lookupGT` to encode the lookup table that is currently done with guards. So:

```
import Data.Map (fromAscList, lookupGT)

calcGrade :: Double -> Double -> Double
calcGrade x y
    | x > 20 = error "Can't add more than 20 extra points"  
    | y > 100 = error "Can't achieve more than 100 points"
    | otherwise = case lookupGT (x+y) cutoffs of
        Just (_, v) -> v
        Nothing -> 1.0
    where
    cutoffs = fromAscList [(50, 5.0), (54, 4.0), (58, 3.7), (62, 3.3), (66, 3.0), (70, 2.7), (74, 2.3), (78, 2.0), (82, 1.7), (86, 1.3)]
```

This has a few advantages:

- Much less repetition. This is a virtue in and of itself.
- With the guards, the reader must carefully check that the condition is on `x+y` in every case, and not, say, the very visually similar `x+v` for some case for some reason. With this encoding, that's clear without careful attention.
- Each guard would be checked in turn, giving a linear runtime in the number of cutoffs. With `Map`'s `lookupGT`, only a log number of comparisons is done. Since you probably don't intend to vary the cutoffs dynamically, this probably doesn't matter; but the trick used here can occasionally be useful elsewhere, so it's nice to remember it for those cases where asymptotics do matter.
- Because cutoffs appear in only one place, if this changes later (you'd be surprised...) you don't have to be careful to change, e.g., `58` to `59` in two places as one would need to do with your code.

The only wart, in my opinion, is that the default score case (`Nothing -> 1.0`) doesn't live next to the cutoffs; though it's not clear to me how one might go about doing that sanely.

Answer (score 1):

If you only accepted `Int` values (and still returned `Double`) then you could write it as

```
calcGrade x y =
    let score = (min 46 (x + y) - 46) `div` 4
        grades = [5.0, 4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3] ++ repeat 1.0
    in grades !! score
```

But this leaves out the first 2 checks.  You could put them in rather easily, but it might be better to put that in a different function (also, the use of `error` is frowned upon in Haskell, better to use a type that indicates the function might fail, such as Maybe or Either).

What this function does is calculates the sum of x and y first, then says "which is smaller, x + y or 46?".  This handles the case of `x + y < 50`.  Next, it subtracts 46, so a score of 50 becomes 4, a score of 54 becomes 8, and so on.  The `div` function will do integer division by 4, so a score of 50 becomes 4 becomes 1, a score less than 50 becomes 0, and a score of 73 becomes 27 becomes 6.

The grades themselves are stored in a list, any score less than 50 will index out the first element of 5.0, and then each range indexes out its corresponding element, so 73 indexes out the 7th element (index 6) of 2.3.  The `++ repeat 1.0` handles a score `>= 86`.

---

Another way you could solve this might make a bit more sense.  Just build a list of the ranges:

```
let score = x + y
    mins = [0, 50, 54, 58, 62, 66, 70, 74, 78, 82, 86, 120]
    ranges = zip mins (tail mins)  -- [(0, 50), (50, 54), ..., (86, 120)]
    grades = [5.0, 4.0, 3.7, 3.3, 3.0, 2.7, 2.3, 2.0, 1.7, 1.3, 1.0]
    inRange = map (\(lower, upper) -> lower <= score && score < upper) ranges
in snd $ head $ filter fst $ zip inRange grades
```

I think most of this logic is pretty clear, but the last line might be confusing.  It zips the `inRange` list of Bools with the grades, filters by the first element (whether that range included the score), takes the first element from the list, then grabs the second element of that `(Bool, Double)` tuple.

Comment: This seems like a very obscure way to implement this function. Without list fusion, the second one would traverse the list four(!) times. The first one is OK, but I would take it one step further and compute the result directly rather than use a spurious O(n) index into a linked list.

Comment: Haskell won't traverse that many times even without list fusion due to laziness.  Try it out in ghci with `:print`, it won't even evaluate all of `ranges` if the score is less than 86.  Also, for a list this small it's pretty fast still.  Worrying about that level of optimization on a beginner problem like this is pointless.

Comment: I'm not worried about actual performance, just if the design is good. Using lists here is really not needed. Probably the lowest barrier to understanding solution would be a Map from scores to grades or whatever the actual function is. Then you can use lookup and get a) proper failure handling b) O(log n) c) all the usual Map functions will work d) introspection into the lookup table (can get list of possible grades for example)

Answer (score 1):

Some things you can try to clean it up a bit:

- Use a [where binding](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) to extract the common subexpression `x + y`.
- Better yet, just accept the already added number as an argument. Then this function will be your "lookup grade" function, and you can call it like `lookupGrade (exam + extra)`.
- Don't use `error`. Instead, return a `Maybe Double` (which is either `Just` a `Double`, or `Nothing` if you can't compute the score.
- List your guards in reverse order. This way, you only have to check one bound on each, not both. It is ok to overlap because they are checked *in order*.
- Try to extract the actual meaning of the grading algorithm, rather than trying to list out cases. Try to find a math formula that converts it like you want, then write that formula in Haskell.

Applying these transformations is probably the best way to write this function, unless you want to use a Map (from `Data.Map`) to list larger numbers of cases. This code will express your intent better than using a bunch of unneeded lists.

Comment: Your suggestion to check in the reverse order is useful, but not because the order matters.  This technique could be applied with this order by not checking the lower bound since it's all done in order.  My second solution could also benefit from it by avoiding the `ranges` list altogether and modifying the `inRange` definition to follow suit.  The last line wouldn't even have to change if done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the performance, but this should work.

```
import Data.Map (fromAscList, filterWithKey)

calculate :: Double -> Double -> String 
calculate exam bonus
  | exam > 20 || bonus > 100 = "Be real!" 
  | otherwise = (foldr (++) "" . filterWithKey isInRange) letterGrade
  where
    isInRange k _ = percent `elem` k
    percent = truncate $ (exam + bonus) * 10 / 12
    letterGrade = fromAscList [ ([90..100], "A"), ([80..89],  "B"), ([70..79],  "C"), ([60..69],  "D"), ([0 ..59],  "F")]
```

Comment: I downvoted. This is clearly not computing the same function; has no discussion; and there are several questionable design decisions (e.g. why use a `Map` if you're just going to walk over every element anyway?).